# How to press 2 key parallel by using pyautogui.press()?

Tags: python-3.6, pyautogui

I wish to save a file so the keyboard shortcut is **'ctrl'+'s'**, I try **pyautogui.press(['ctrlleft','s'])** but it end up it press key simultaneously. So how to make it happen by pressing the keys parrallel so that the save function can achieve.

Comment: `pyautogui.hotkey('ctrlleft', 's')` Helpful to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the **hotkey()** can be passed several key strings which will be pressed down in order, and then released in reverse order

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrlleft', 's')
```

Reference:https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html